# How to move and overwrite subdirectories (and files) to parent directory?

Tags: shell, command-line, files

I have a ton of files and dirs in a subdirectory I want to move to the parent directory. There are already some files and dirs in the target directory which need to be overwritten. Files that are only present in the target should be left untouched. Can I force `mv`to do that? It (`mv * ..`) complains

```
mv: cannot move `xyz' to `../xyz': Directory not empty
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You will have to copy them to the destination and then delete the source, using the commands `cp -r * ..` followed by `rm -rf *`.

I don't think you can "merge" directories using `mv`.

Comment: Well, that's what I didn't want to do, because it will take a long time... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Presumably `mv` is faster because you're on the same filesystem? What if you use `cp -l` to create hardlinks rather than actually moving the files?

Comment: You should use `cp -a` instead of `cp -r` in order to preserve the file attributes (timestamp, permissions, etc.).

Comment: For people arriving here late via google, the answer below by @palswim emulates the behavior of mv by creating new hard links to the data and then deleting the old links. Short answer `cp -rl source destination && rm -r source`.

Comment: Always BE CAREFUL when using `rm -rf`, be sure to specify the folder name at the end and to not use variables if you are in script, you might end up running `rm -rf /` and this will "kind" break your server.

Comment: @elvis meaning: always have backups! 

Answer (score 100):

`rsync` would probably be a better option here.  It's as simple as `rsync -a subdir/ ./`.

My test tree in `filename`:`contents` format:

```
./file1:root
./file2:root
./dir/file3:dir
./dir/file4:dir
./subdir/dir/file3:subdir
./subdir/file1:subdir
```

Running `rsync`:

```
$ rsync -a -v subdir/ ./
sending incremental file list
./
file1
dir/
dir/file3
```

Gives:

```
./file1:subdir
./file2:root
./dir/file3:subdir
./dir/file4:dir
./subdir/dir/file3:subdir
./subdir/file1:subdir
```

And then, to emulate `mv`, you probably want to remove the source directory:

```
$ rm -r subdir/
```

Giving:

```
./file1:subdir
./file2:root
./dir/file3:subdir
./dir/file4:dir
```

If this is wrong, can you please provide a similar example (e.g. using my test tree from near the top of this answer) with the desired result?

Comment: rsync copies. This question is about moving.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks.  I added `rm -r` at the end to make it basically the same as `mv`.

Comment: copy-then-delete isn't equivalent to mv when the source and destination are on the same filesystem. `mv` is atomic, preserves inode numbers (so the file can remain open), and doesn't take time and space making a copy.

Comment: @Gilles: I realize that, but currently the leading answer is `cp -r; rm -r`.  I think in that sense, `rsync` is worth mentioning too.

Comment: I already did it with cp/rm (it was urgent). It really took a long time. Gilles script would probably have been a lot quicker, but he was too late too.

Comment: +1 did the job for me.  You may want to run "diff -rq source_dir dest_dir" before proceeding with the rsync.

Comment: this is a much better way, the other way you have to agree to overwrite every file, on centos 5.9 anyway, for some reason -f doesn't solve that :/

Comment: This is totally incorrect. rsync as you have shown it is an incremental copy. You need to add the --delete, option.

Answer (score 73):

`rsync` can delete the source after copying with the `--remove-source-files` parameter.

From the `rsync` man page:

```
--remove-source-files   sender removes synchronized files (non-dir)
```

Comment: This is really the best answer. I couldn't use `cp -r; rm` because of lack of free space. Instead `rsync --remove-source-files` both minimized used disk space avoided copying over the exact same files.

Comment: Maybe  --link-dest to.

Comment: That leaves empty folders in place. Is there a flag to get rid of empty folders?

Answer (score 42):

You can do this with `cp` and `rm`, but without copying the massive amount of data you are (presumably) trying to avoid transferring. @mattdm alluded to this in [his comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9899/13308#comment12749_9902), and [an answer for another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/172402/13308) has a more complete discussion about various options.

```
cp -rlf source destination
rm -r source
```

Essentially, the `-l` option for the `cp` command creates hard links to files rather than copying their data to new files.

Comment: I know the [OP already completed his task](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9899/13308#comment12812_9920) which prompted the question, but hopefully this answer can help anyone with this problem in the future.

Comment: This really the answer they needed.  I just did this with 60GB of thousands of small cyrus email files and it took only 21 seconds.

Comment: This is also the route I took - I just changed it to `cp -al source destination` to preserve owner info and permissions.

Comment: I think to actually do what OP asked for you have to add the -f option otherwise it will not overwrite if the file exists. Can you confirm that or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @dasKeks: Actually, `cp` overwrites by default. The `-f` option attempts to remove the file (as in `rm`) before trying to copy anew, which can help if the process can't open the file for writing, though some people would prefer to see that there was an error instead. I don't know if it mattered to the OP, but I added the `-f` flag to my answer anyway.

Comment: should probably use `cp -ralf` as default. but only works where hardlinks are accepted, obviously! sadly, not in termux

Answer (score 10):

Here's a script that moves files from under `/path/to/source/root` to the corresponding path under `/path/to/destination/root`.

- If a directory exists in both the source and the destination, the contents are moved-and-merged recursively.
- If a file or directory exists in the source but not in the destination, it is moved.
- Any file or directory that already exists in the destination is left behind. (In particular merged directories are left behind in the source. This is not easy to fix.)

Beware, untested code.

```
export dest='/path/to/destination/root'
cd /path/to/source/root
find . -type d \( -exec sh -c '[ -d "$dest/$0" ]' {} \; -o \
                  -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$dest/$0"' {} \; -prune \) \
    -o -exec sh -c '
        if ! [ -e "$dest/$0" ]; then
          mv -f "$0" "$dest/$0";
        fi
' {} \;
```

Comment: Two corrections: you need a `\;` before the `-o` on the first line of the `find` command, and you shouldn't escape `!` in the `if` -- it's just `!`, not `\!`

Comment: Does not work - I get: mv: cannot move '.' to '/<dest>/./.': Device or resource busy. I would like to move stuff from /a/b to /a

Comment: @Gerfried I just fixed a mistake in the code that skips existing directories. Please try again.

Answer (score 4):

This thread is out there for years and still ranks #1 on google so i wanted to add another method.
How i usually do this:
packing the subdir content into a tarball, moving the tarball up to the parent directory and then extract it with the default --overwrite behaviour. This does exactly what you're looking for. Afterwards you can remove your subdir.

```
cd xyz
tar -cvzpf tmp.tar.gz *
mv tmp.tar.gz ../tmp.tar.gz
cd ..
tar -xvzpf tmp.tar.gz
rm -rf xyz
rm -f tmp.tar.gz
```

Comment: This only works if you have the extra space for the compressed tar file. And do you really want to keep the temporary tar file around after extraction?

Comment: Edited code to remove tmp file. Nowadays the space isn't the problem in the most cases. #terabyteages

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough storage you can do it the following way:

```
mv -bfv directory_1/* directory_2/ # all duplicate source files/directories 
                                   # will have ~ appended to them
find -name "*~" -delete            # will recursively find and delete all files 
                                   # with ~ on the end
```

Make sure there aren't any important files with a ~ on the end of them, but if there are you can add `--suffix=whateveryouwant` instead of the default.