# How to copy-merge two directories?

Tags: ubuntu, directory, file-copy

I have two directories images and images2 with this structure in Linux:

```
/images/ad  
/images/fe  
/images/foo
```

... and other 4000 folders

and the other is like:

```
/images2/ad  
/images2/fe  
/images2/foo
```

... and other 4000 folders

Each of these folders contain images and the directories' names under images and images2 are exactly the same, however their content is different. Then I want to know how I can copy-merge the images of /images2/ad into images/ad, the images of /images2/foo into images/foo and so on with all the 4000 folders..

Comment: are the end files named the same in both directories?

Comment: Nope... for example in images/ad are 1.jpg, 2.jpg and 3.jpg. But in images2/ad are 4.jpg and 5.jpg

Comment: @AmirAliAkbari, I don't think that it is a duplicate - the other question basically is 'Does mv do merging?' (answer: no). This question is about how to merge 2 directory hierarchies.

Comment: can't believe `cp` doesn't have an option for this...

Comment: I can't believe people don't know that `cp` does have this option. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

This is a job for [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). There's no benefit to doing this manually with a shell loop unless you want to move the file rather than copy them.

```
rsync -a /path/to/source/ /path/to/destination
```

In your case:

```
rsync -a /images2/ /images/
```

(Note trailing slash on `images2`, otherwise it would copy to `/images/images2`.)

If images with the same name exist in both directories, the command above will overwrite `/images/SOMEPATH/SOMEFILE` with `/images2/SOMEPATH/SOMEFILE`. If you want to replace only older files, add the option `-u`. If you want to always keep the version in `/images`, add the option `--ignore-existing`.

If you want to move the files from `/images2`, with rsync, you can pass the option `--remove-source-files`. Then rsync copies all the files in turn, and removes each file when it's done. This is a lot slower than moving if the source and destination directories are on the same filesystem.

Comment: ..add -P if you'd like to see progress..

Comment: I would add that there's no benefit to using a tricky shell loop here even if you *do* want to move them instead of copying them—in that case just use `rsync`, then `rm -r /images`.

Comment: @Wildcard, well, that's not quite the same as moving. As Gilles points out, it's a lot slower than moving if they're on the same fs; and moreover it requires a lot more temporary spae.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that **it's important to include the trailing slashes for each directory**. For example, if you simply ran `rsync -a images images2`, it will just copy images2 into images instead of merging them.

Comment: FWIW, in the order of the directories in the command here is backward from the user's original question—as written, this answer will copy the contents of /images/ into /images2/, but the user's question had it going the other way around.

Comment: @s3cur3 Oh. From 2 to (implicit) 1. That's unintuitive. Thanks, I fixed my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to make rsync ASK you if you want to overwrite or not?

Comment: @MaxCoplan No. Rsync isn't an interactive tool.

Comment: Running `rsync -a /path/to/source/ /path/to/destination` helped me fix a problem where a mv job was interrupted. Thank you!

Answer (score 80):

The best choice, as already posted, is of course `rsync`. Nevertheless also `unison` would be a great piece of software to do this job, though typically requires a package install. Both can be used in several operating systems.

### Rsync

rsync synchronizes in one direction from source to destination.
Therefore the following statement

```
rsync -avh --progress Source Destination
```

syncs everything from **Source** to **Destination**. The merged folder resides in **Destination**.

**-a** means "archive" and copies everything recursively from source to destination preserving nearly everything.

**-v** gives more output ("verbose").

**-h** for human readable.

**--progress** to show how much work is done.

If you want only **update** the **destination** folder **with newer** files from source folder:

```
rsync -avhu --progress source destination
```

## Unison

unison synchronizes in both directions. Therefore the following statement

```
unison Source Destination
```

syncs both directories in both directions and finally source equals destination. It's like doing rsync twice from source to dest and vice versa.

For more advanced usages look at the man pages or the following websites:

1. [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/)
2. https://rsync.samba.org/

Comment: I want to mention that the correct path to the folder should be with the trailing slash at the end `rsync -avh --progress source/ destination/` , otherwise source folder will be created in destination folder, at least in my case that was like this.

Comment: This works great for me (with the trailing slash in folders). Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

There are faster and much more space-efficient ways of merging two directories using the `--link` option to `cp` if the directories are *on the same file system*, described in the multiple varied answers in a related article here:  (The title of the article doesn't exactly match the user's question, and the answers address the title topic, merging, more than they address the user's actual question.)

[Merging folders with mv?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127712/merging-folders-with-mv)

The `--link` option to `cp` means no file data is copied.  An example of this, where everything in `/images2` replaces any older items in `/images` is:

`cp --force --archive --update --link /images2/. /images`

After the merge into `/images`, you can then `rm -rf /images2`

This solution will fail if anywhere in the file tree the merge tries to merge a directory onto an existing file or symlink with the same name, i.e. it won't merge a directory named `/images2/x` onto an existing file or symlink with the same name `/images/x` and if you get such an error you can manually delete the file or symlink and just re-run the command.

The nice thing about `--link` is that no data is moved to merge the directories.

Comment: In particular it doesn't require lots of temporary space... I just needed to merge two large folders (several TBs each) and that's a much better way!

Answer (score 8):

The answer to this question is dead simple. I have used it many times.

All you need to do is ...

```
cp -rf source_folder parent_of_dest_folder
```

Using the specific file structure in the original question, the command would be...

```
cp -rf /images/* /images2/
```

The result will be a merged version of source and the destination. This will also process subdirectories recursively.

As pointed out by @ingyhere, the above commands will override existing files in the destination directory. If you wish to keep existing files, then you must ad the `-n` parameter to the `cp` command. Read more about this in the `cp` man page at [https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html#:~:text=links%20in%20SOURCE-,%2Dn%2C%20%2D%2Dno%2Dclobber,-do%20not%20overwrite](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html#:%7E:text=links%20in%20SOURCE-,%2Dn%2C%20%2D%2Dno%2Dclobber,-do%20not%20overwrite)

```
cp -rfn /images/* /images2/
```

Comment: Good question. However, in a typical situation, if you are trying to merge a source directory into a destination, it means that the source files are more relevant in the event that some of them exist at the destination.

That said, if you want to keep existing files, then use the `-n` option. Read more about it at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html#:~:text=links%20in%20SOURCE-,%2Dn%2C%20%2D%2Dno%2Dclobber,-do%20not%20overwrite. I will update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: According to the man page you shared, the `-f` option is ignored when `-n` is present

Answer (score 7):

```
for dir in images2/*; do mv "$dir"/* "images/$(basename "$dir")"; done
```

Loop over all the contents of `images2` using an expanded glob (to avoid the problems with parsing `ls`) then `mv` the contents of those items to the matching entry in `images`. Uses `basename` to strip the leading `images2` from the globbed path.

Comment: I know this is really old, but is there a convenient way to modify this to only copy the files that contain a certain string in their name?  something like `if filename like '*2160*' then mv`

Answer (score 6):

This effectively merges using the `cp` command without overwriting:

```
cp -prnv /images/* /images2/
```

Options:

```
-p -- preserve ownership, perms and detailed attributes
-r -- recursive
-n -- no overwrite
-v -- verbose (display operation detail for each file)
```

To see what actually was copied, run it this way:

```
cp -prnv /images/* /images2/ | grep '\->'  # shows copies
```

To see the opposite of what didn't copy, use `grep -v '\->'`.

If you want to do something more complex, like replacing files with differences, use `rsync` or fly your own by testing the `md5sum` on both sides then copying based on the `diff` exit code (not recommended for large files or big directories -- use `rsync`).

Answer (score 1):

@inulinux12 , you can use the following one line `for` loop from command line:

```
$ for dir in images2/*; do mv "$dir"/* "${dir/2/}"; done
```

This will move all of the files from `images2` to `images` in their respective directories. Note: this assumes no files have the same name.

For example:

Before execution:

```
$ ls -R images*
images:
ad  adfoo  fe
images/ad:
jpg.1  jpg.2
images/adfoo:
jpg.7
images/fe:
jpg.5
images2:
ad  adfoo  fe
images2/ad:
jpg.3
images2/adfoo:
jpg.6
images2/fe:
jpg.4
```

After execution:

```
$ ls -R images*
images:
ad  adfoo  fe
images/ad:
jpg.1  jpg.2  jpg.3
images/adfoo:
jpg.6  jpg.7
images/fe:
jpg.4  jpg.5
```

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you for the suggestion; seems pretty narrow scenarios though given the information given in the question.

Comment: @Simply_Me While true that it will usually be fine, you really don't want it to blow up when you hit a case you weren't counting on. It can cause **really** bad problems. Not to mention that it is quite often (as in this case) almost trivially replaceable with a simple glob. See my answer as an example of that.

Comment: @Simply_Me The scenarios include file names with spaces, which is pretty common for images.

Comment: @Gilles and @Etan Reisner , thank you for the input, I appreciate it! Updated and tested my answer to use string substitution, and it came to be faster than using `basename` in this particular situation (no need to call `basename` for this). Thanks again for constructive comments.

Comment: This command line won't move images in hidden directories or image file names starting with a dot (period) such as `images/.dir` or `images/ad/.foo.jpg`, nor will it handle images in sub-directories such as `images/ad/dir/`

Answer (score 1):

merge_dirs.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# filename: merge_dirs.sh

SOURCE=/images2
TARGET=/images

cd "$SOURCE"
# duplicate the directory structure into TARGET, no files
find . -type d -exec mkdir -vp "$TARGET/{}" ';'
# move files from SOURCE to TARGET, skip if existing
find . -type f -exec mv -vn '{}' "$TARGET/{}" ';'
cd "$OLDPWD"
# optional: remove all empty directories from SOURCE
find "$SOURCE" -type d -empty -exec rmdir -vp '{}' '+'
```

merge_dirs.sh will give you a merged TARGET. Anything left in SOURCE was a duplicate filename. Whether to delete those is a different problem, but you can always make a script like cmp_rm.sh.

cmp_rm.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# WARNING: THIS SCRIPT DELETES THINGS
# filename: cmp_rm.sh
cmp "$1" "$2" && rm -v "$1"  -i  # -i: prompt before deletion
```

and run:

```
find "$SOURCE" -type f -exec ./cmp_rm.sh '{}' "$TARGET/{}" ';'
```

Comment: I like this because it allows writing scripts for systems where installing additional binaries isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

kdiff3 has an awesome, if slightly frustrating, interactive [merge tool](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/merging.html) that can merge up to three directories into a fourth output directory.

Answer (score -2):

Another simple solution is to make an archive of `images/`:

```bsh
~$ zip -1 images/* images.zip
```

then unpack `images.zip` into `images2/`

```bsh
~$ unzip images.zip images2/
```

Comment: Can you explain why `zip` is useful here?

Comment: @Spooler upon decompressing zip overlays the paths: "path1/sub1/file1.ext" is unpacked into "outpath/path1/sub1/file.ext" - essentially the two zip commands are a shortcut for the bash code "for f in $(find images/ -type f); do mv $f images2/${f/images\//}; done