# Why did rsync hose my root file system when trying to merge in drivers?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, directory, file-copy, android

On a computer I've been working on trying to get going for a LONG time now and still have not completely managed to do so, I tried the following, based on a suggestion from here:

[How to copy-merge two directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149965/how-to-copy-merge-two-directories)

as part of trying to merge a driver tree into the Linux system folders:

```
rsync -aP ./ /
```

where the current directory contains some `etc`, `bin`, etc. folders and I was hoping that, given this is mentioned as how you merge directories, it would just merge in the drivers and configs from those into the main system so I didn't have to painfully `mkdir` and `cp` from every little subdirectory. It ran, and seemed OK. then I typed `ls` as usual to check the effects and got the dreaded

```
sh: ls: not found.
```

**OOPS.**

Now this "system", actually an attempt to load and get Ubuntu 20.04 working, was actually being babysit via a `chroot` from an Android master install on the same machine, and I used the inner `rsync` to do the merge - not sure if that is part of what happened. But weirdly, after exiting the `chroot` and doing a `ls` (now running Android's `ls`) on the `/bin` now as just a normal subdirectory, *ls was still there!* As was pretty much everything else you'd expect. But oddly now, I *can't* `chroot` into it again, as the `chroot` fails with

```
chroot: exec /bin/sh: No such file or directory
```

even though from outside the `chroot`, I can clearly see `/bin/sh` sitting there. But even weirder, though, is when I try to execute that `ls` from *outside* the `chroot` - note here I have the rootfs in question mounted on `/mnt/hdd0`:

```
127|rk3588_firefly_itx_3588j:/mnt # hdd0/bin/sh
/system/bin/sh: hdd0/bin/sh: No such file or directory
```

And `ls hdd0/bin/sh`:

```
rk3588_firefly_itx_3588j:/mnt # ls -l hdd0/bin/sh                              
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2022-11-28 09:04 hdd0/bin/sh -> dash
```

What has happened to the file system?! Oh yeah by the way, yes `dash` does exist:

```
rk3588_firefly_itx_3588j:/mnt # ls -l hdd0/bin/dash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 137728 2019-07-18 18:15 hdd0/bin/dash
```

And yes, Android is okay; it was just the `chroot`ed rootfs (which by the way is actually on an attached SSD, Android is on the board eMMC) that went sour. Oh yeah and note that this system, because it's still not road-ready, has no valuable data so this wasn't a big loss, but I'd like to see if I can recover the filesystem without reformatting the SSD and reloading. I did an `e2fsck -f /dev/block/sda2` with some intriguing results:

```
rk3588_firefly_itx_3588j:/mnt # e2fsck -f /dev/block/sda2
e2fsck 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
/dev/block/sda2: recovering journal
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong (38957201, counted=38810171).
Fix<y>? y
yes
Free inodes count wrong (9920272, counted=9920042).
Fix<y>? yes

/dev/block/sda2: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/block/sda2: 16854/9936896 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 922966/39733137 blocks
```

Not sure what that "Free blocks count wrong" part implies or implied. But it did **not** cure the sick filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Looking at the command you show, you asked to copy everything from the folder you are/were to the root of the filesystem, recursively, in archive mode, with a progress bar and keeping partially-transferred files in the destination.  If you had a `bin` directory under the directory you started in, then you copied a `bin` directory over another `bin` directory... And, if any of the files in the original `bin` directory had the same name as the files in the destination, the extant files in the destination got overwritten.

What directory were you in when you issued the `rsync` command? I wonder if you just copied part of the Android filesystem to the root of the linux drive.  Remember that while Android uses the linux kernel, it is not compatible with most server/desktop/laptop linux systems.  The architectures between the two are completely different (e.g. "x86[_64]" vs "arm[64]").  You can't take a module from Android, move it to a PC and expect it to work, generally.

From the output of trying to `chroot`, it does seem like you have corrupted the linux system, but that isn't that much of an issue.  I would recommend just running the Ubuntu install script and point it directly at the sda/linux drive for install.

Lastly, the "Free blocks count wrong" message just means that when `e2fsck` ran, it saw some entries saying that certain blocks and inodes were supposed to be in use, but couldn't find anything using them so it re-added them to the Free list.

I hope that helps.

Comment: B.Kaatz: Thanks. I've actually done this install before just not with the graphics drivers loaded. I was in the directory containing the driver files being copied. It was a self-prepared package that contained only those files but in the right spots in the directory tree, so it had nothing else there that I am aware of. Certainly not ls, sh, etc. Also for this machine the architectures are the same. It's an ARM board, by the Chinese manufacturer Firefly (this one is very new), so both are ARM64. The trick is because of that, I _can't_ use the usual installer: both board and

Comment: ARM SoC, ROCKCHIP RK3588, were only released this year, and mainstream Kernel support is far from complete. I can only use the nonstandard patched kernel source tree that comes with it. Though maybe I can somehow graft that kernel into an Ubuntu installer, but I don't know to how to decompress those "squash" files and put them together again.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer: Ahh... I see.  Well, if this just a test system to play/test/learn/"hack" on, have you seen if Gentoo has the support you need?  On just checking a search in `make menuconfig` on kv 5.15.30 (which is already considered "old" by Gentoo standards), I see 55 kernel configs directly pertaining to Rockchip support for things like Clock, PCIe, video (including a decoder driver), sound, ASoC support for boards using the RT5645/RT5650 codec or the MAX98090 codec, plus much more.  If you get a chance, I would recommend trying out Gentoo's ARM64 Handbook with a current kernel and see.