# Copying/Moving folders where destination folder already exists

Tags: shell-script, scripting, directory, rename

I am writing a bash script to copy/move a folder called "folder" to a directory that already contains "folder" and I would like the contents to be merged.

I am attempting to use a solution from this question:

[Merging folders with mv?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127712/merging-folders-with-mv)

```
cp -rl source/folder destination
rm -r source/folder
```

If i type the first line in the terminal, source "folder" and destination "folder" are merged as expected.

However, When i run the script with the line in it, instead of merging the folders the destination now contains two folders; "folder" and "blank", where "blank" has the contents of the source "folder" in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "blank named folder"? The content of `source/folder` was not copied to `destination/folder`?

Comment: After i run the script, destination now contains two folders; "folder" and "blank", where "blank" has the contents of the source "folder" in it.

Comment: 1. are you using variables to hold the source and destination directory names?  2. if so, are you double-quoting the variables when you use them (i.e. `cp "$source" "$destination"` rather than `cp $source $destination` - the latter, without the double-quotes, will fail in all sorts of cases that the former, with quotes, will handle without problem).  see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: @cas It's a very short script so currently the source and destination are hard coded: cp -rl /volume1/Sync/TVSync/* /volume1/Sync/TempSync/

Comment: ok, so not a whitespace issue then.   what do you mean by "blank named folder"?

Comment: @cas when i type the first line in the terminal, source "folder" and destination "folder" are merged. When i run the script with the line in it, instead of merging the folders the destination now contains two folders; "folder" and "blank", where "blank" has the contents of the source "folder" in it.

Answer (score 0):

To append SOURCE to DESTINATION to become SOUCE+DESTINATION is more complicated (for self), look up

```
 man append
```

You might try:

```
    cp  --recursive  --preserve --update  SOURCE DESTINATION
```

use  "--preserve"  to preserve the specified attributes 
               (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), 
               if possible additional attributes: context, 
               links, xattr, all

use  "--recursive"   to copy directories recursively

use   "--update"      to copy when the SOURCE file is newer
                       than the destination file or when the
                       destination file is missing.

For help in terminal:

```
   cp --help
```

or

```
  man cp
```

When terminal works, try it in your bash script

.

Comment: Thanks @polpak , the odd thing is that the first line works as expected in the terminal but not in the script. I'll edit the question to mention that.

Comment: From help     -l, --link                   hard link files instead of copying
      -L, --dereference            always follow symbolic links in SOURCE

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better way of doing this would be to use a better tool.

```bash
rsync -avhP --remove-source-files "source/folder" destination
```

`-a` is for archiving (keep user/group, modes, etc. in tact)

`-v` just for verbosity, so you can watch what it's doing

`-h` because I like Human Readable info

`-P` so rsync will pick up on partial transfers, just in case

`--remove-source-files` will remove everything that rsync transfers

I find that I often have to kludge empty folder removal as housekeeping:

```bash
find source/folder -type d -exec rmdir {} \;
```

I prepend that in `zsh` with `repeat 10` and it cleans 10 levels deep of empty folders.  :-)