# How to override all folders with cp?

Tags: linux, cp

I have two folders, and I would like to do:

```
 cp -R folder1/ folder2/
```

So that I all the sub folders missing in folder2 will be created, and there files copied. And all the folders in folder2 that are missing from folder1 stay the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cp -R folder1/. folder2/
```

You can use `folder1/*` instead, if you don't mind that `*` will not match "hidden" files which begin with a `.` like `.bash_profile`.

If there are files in folder2 with the same name as files in folder1, they will be overwritten without prompting or warning.

Comment: and the files that only exists in folder2 wont be deleted ?

Comment: no.  cp doesn't delete files.  (`rsync` does _if you pass --delete_).

Answer (score 5):

```
cp -fR folder1/ folder2/
```

the -f flag forces the dest file to be deleted if cannot be opened

[see man page for cp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html)

Also, another option would be to use **rsync**, see this answer for example:

[How to overwrite target files with mv?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9899/how-to-overwrite-target-files-with-mv)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `cp`, instead use `mv`, Because:
`cp` copy all files and it spreads time and I/O, But `mv` only change inode:
So:

```
mv -f dir1/ dir2
```