# Moving contents of current directory up one level and overwriting if exists recursively

Tags: centos, mv

I've unpackaged a zip into the current location which we'll call `/httpdocs`, everything inside the zip resides in a directory which we'll call `myfiles`.

In `/httpdocs` are thousands of directories and files that also exist at exactly the same paths as in the `myfiles` directory.

I need to move the contents of the `myfiles` directory into `/httpdocs` whilst replacing any directories/files that already exist... recursively.

If I try from the `myfiles` directory:

```
mv * ../
```

I am asked if I want to overwrite if exists... y/n for every single file!

If I try from `/httpdocs`:

```
mv myfiles/* .
```

I am asked if I want to overwrite if exists... y/n for every single file!

If I try to apply the `-f` force operator, it returns that it cannot move because the `Directory not empty`.

---

Now from what I have read, it doesn't seem like what I am trying to do is achievable with the `mv` command which is probably why I am seem to be getting absolutely nowhere with this.

I am aware of `cp` and `rsync` and many others but I am not sure which command is the best to use to actually just move the contents of the directory to another location and overwrite if exists recursively.

---

I know I could do this easily by just uploading to `/httpdocs` via FTP in any local client and just 'Yes to all' on the overwrite dialogue but it would just take ages so not always practical - I'm just after a like-for-like over the command line really.

Comment: I am not sure what the answer is on that question @Haxiel because the accepted answer states use `cp` like `cp -r * ..` from my `myfiles` directory yet when I try that, I am asked y/n to overwrite for every file still. This is what I mean by I can't find something online that actually does what I am seeking.

Comment: `cp` should overwrite existing files by default. Can you check if you have an alias configured for cp in your environment? It may be mapped to `cp -i` or so.

Comment: You are spot on. `which cp` returns `alias cp='cp -i' /bin/cp` - no wonder this has been doing my head in all of this time. Will try and remove the alias and try again. Thanks.

Comment: For reference, the comment by @Haxiel led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8488292/898933)...

Comment: Bypassed for current session with `unalias cp` and the `cp` command worked perfectly as it should do. Thank you @Haxiel for directing me to the problem (never knew about command aliases) - I do believe my question/scenario is different to that of the suggested duplicate question though and I will accept an answer if you wanted to add it.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked out. I'll add a brief answer here, as asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed under [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9899/173368), the `mv` command does not directly provide a way to 'merge' directories by overwriting existing files.

The `cp` and `rm` commands can be used together as an equivalent alternative. In this case, the command would be:

```
cd /path/to/httpdocs
cp -r myfiles/* .
rm -r myfiles/
```

Note: The `cp` command overwrites existing files by default. The OP had an alias interfering with this process. The `cp` command was aliased to `cp -i`, which asks for interactive confirmation on each overwrite. This can be overridden by running `unalias cp` first, or using the `\cp -r ..` syntax.